# Turn off black notification/clock screen on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, clock

When I turn on my Samsung Galaxy S4, it often comes with a black clock/notification screen.

[image]

How to turn it off?

Comment: Cant take screenshot when it's there. It looks like the always on display on newer Samsungs. It is only there for 10sec.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a lockscreen widget, anyway try this:

Drag down the screen from where the message and
clock is.
Delete text and uncheck clock then press save (just needs to be edited from the lock screen).

You may need to disable your lock
security while editing.
Then tap save in the top right and your lock screen will be clear